# Convert and compare two date formats in JAVA

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

In my application I am having two different types of date formats. One gives **Thu Apr 19 12:10:26 GMT+05:30 2012** as out put and other one gives **1334654035000** as out put.

Can I change the first format to the second type (which has only numbers) ?
The reason is,I have to compare two different dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compare two dates formatted differently,

- parse the first string with the appropriate date format to transform the string into a Date
- parse the second string with the appropriate date format to transform the string into a Date
- compare the Date objects

Comment: Yep, that is working. I tried other way. Means I tried to convert the String in to the long value and compare. But it is easy to compare with String values. Thanks.

Comment: This would be a beneficial answer if you actually gave examples of the code.

Answer (score 0):

using the parse method of java.text.SimpleDateFormat should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could do it. If we assume the dates are under the same time zone, convert the dates using SimpleDateFormat class to Calendar and then invoke the methods on Calendar object to compare dates.

Answer (score 0):

parse the date and and compare the date

```
                 if(!sToDate[Integer.valueOf(sChecked[i])].equalsIgnoreCase("")&&!sFromDate[Integer.valueOf(sChecked[i])].equalsIgnoreCase(""))
```

if(sToDate[Integer.parseInt(sChecked[i])].compareTo(sFromDate[Integer.parseInt(sChecked[i])])<0)